# How to get the value from duplicate element in JSON?

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, json.net

I am trying to extract text from image using Microsoft Computer vision and using Blue Prism (RPA tool). I have a JSON response like below:

```
{
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResults": [{
    "page": 1,
    "clockwiseOrientation": 0.76,
    "width": 1700,
    "height": 2200,
    "unit": "pixel",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": [691, 55, 854, 57, 853, 78, 690, 76],
      "text": "Display Record",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [695, 56, 775, 57, 776, 77, 695, 76],
        "text": "Display"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [783, 57, 853, 58, 854, 79, 783, 78],
        "text": "Record"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [57, 102, 397, 107, 396, 130, 56, 126],
      "text": "Customer Number . . 0012343345",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [60, 103, 153, 106, 153, 127, 60, 124],
        "text": "Customer"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [160, 106, 230, 107, 230, 129, 160, 128],
        "text": "Number"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [242, 108, 256, 108, 255, 129, 241, 129],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [264, 108, 278, 108, 278, 130, 264, 129],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [284, 108, 397, 107, 396, 130, 284, 130],
        "text": "0012343345"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [685, 110, 1126, 115, 1125, 140, 684, 136],
      "text": "Short Name . . . . . . SHOES AND THINGS",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [685, 111, 742, 114, 742, 135, 685, 133],
        "text": "Short"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [749, 114, 798, 116, 798, 137, 749, 135],
        "text": "Name"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [808, 117, 823, 117, 823, 137, 808, 137],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [830, 117, 844, 117, 844, 138, 830, 138],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [851, 118, 866, 118, 866, 138, 851, 138],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [874, 118, 889, 118, 889, 139, 874, 139],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [897, 118, 912, 119, 912, 139, 897, 139],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [919, 119, 933, 119, 933, 139, 919, 139],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [940, 119, 999, 118, 999, 139, 940, 139],
        "text": "SHOES"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1005, 118, 1042, 118, 1042, 139, 1005, 139],
        "text": "AND"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1051, 118, 1121, 115, 1121, 138, 1051, 139],
        "text": "THINGS"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [57, 132, 366, 135, 365, 159, 56, 155],
      "text": "Name . . . SHOES AND THINGS",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [59, 132, 109, 134, 108, 156, 58, 155],
        "text": "Name"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [118, 134, 133, 134, 132, 157, 117, 156],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [141, 134, 156, 135, 155, 157, 140, 157],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [163, 135, 178, 135, 178, 157, 163, 157],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [183, 135, 243, 136, 243, 158, 182, 157],
        "text": "SHOES"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [249, 136, 287, 137, 286, 158, 249, 158],
        "text": "AND"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [296, 137, 366, 138, 365, 157, 296, 158],
        "text": "THINGS"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [682, 139, 930, 143, 929, 167, 682, 163],
      "text": "Legal Residence Code .",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [683, 141, 743, 141, 742, 163, 682, 163],
        "text": "Legal"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [749, 141, 855, 143, 854, 164, 748, 163],
        "text": "Residence"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [862, 144, 911, 146, 910, 165, 861, 164],
        "text": "Code"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [920, 147, 930, 148, 929, 166, 918, 166],
        "text": "."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [682, 279, 1066, 284, 1065, 305, 682, 301],
      "text": "Date of Registration/ Incorporation",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [683, 280, 729, 281, 728, 301, 682, 301],
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [737, 281, 763, 282, 762, 301, 736, 301],
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [771, 282, 913, 284, 912, 303, 770, 301],
        "text": "Registration/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [917, 284, 1063, 285, 1061, 305, 916, 303],
        "text": "Incorporation"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1083, 282, 1192, 284, 1191, 307, 1082, 305],
      "text": "2/14/2016",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1094, 284, 1192, 285, 1191, 307, 1094, 305],
        "text": "2/14/2016"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [57, 326, 454, 332, 453, 356, 56, 350],
      "text": "Email Addr SHOESANDTHINGS@YAHOO . COM",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [58, 327, 119, 328, 118, 351, 57, 350],
        "text": "Email"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [125, 328, 174, 329, 173, 352, 124, 351],
        "text": "Addr"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [181, 329, 402, 333, 402, 354, 181, 352],
        "text": "SHOESANDTHINGS@YAHOO"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [407, 333, 412, 334, 411, 355, 407, 355],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [416, 334, 451, 334, 451, 355, 416, 355],
        "text": "COM"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [680, 335, 951, 338, 950, 359, 679, 356],
      "text": "Customer Risk Class . N",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [681, 336, 772, 336, 772, 358, 681, 355],
        "text": "Customer"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [781, 336, 827, 337, 827, 358, 781, 358],
        "text": "Risk"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [837, 337, 896, 339, 896, 358, 837, 358],
        "text": "Class"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [917, 339, 930, 340, 930, 357, 918, 358],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [936, 340, 949, 340, 950, 357, 937, 357],
        "text": "N"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [54, 356, 236, 358, 236, 383, 53, 380],
      "text": "National ID Nbr",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [57, 358, 153, 358, 153, 381, 56, 380],
        "text": "National"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [161, 358, 185, 359, 184, 382, 160, 381],
        "text": "ID"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [191, 359, 230, 360, 230, 383, 190, 382],
        "text": "Nbr",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [676, 362, 757, 366, 756, 387, 675, 382],
      "text": "Remarks",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [680, 364, 756, 369, 756, 386, 680, 384],
        "text": "Remarks"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [58, 386, 185, 388, 184, 408, 57, 406],
      "text": "Tax ID Cert",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [59, 386, 93, 387, 93, 407, 59, 406],
        "text": "Tax"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [104, 387, 126, 388, 126, 407, 104, 407],
        "text": "ID"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [136, 388, 183, 389, 183, 407, 136, 407],
        "text": "Cert"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [676, 390, 925, 396, 924, 417, 675, 412],
      "text": "Originating Branch . .",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [680, 392, 805, 395, 804, 415, 680, 410],
        "text": "Originating"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [814, 395, 881, 396, 881, 416, 813, 415],
        "text": "Branch"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [895, 396, 907, 396, 906, 416, 895, 416],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [917, 396, 924, 396, 924, 416, 917, 416],
        "text": "."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [952, 396, 994, 396, 994, 414, 953, 413],
      "text": "126",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [960, 395, 993, 395, 993, 413, 960, 413],
        "text": "126"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1030, 394, 1376, 397, 1375, 420, 1029, 417],
      "text": "Date Last Tagged . . 2/04/2019",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1035, 396, 1082, 397, 1083, 417, 1035, 415],
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1091, 397, 1138, 397, 1139, 418, 1091, 417],
        "text": "Last"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1148, 397, 1217, 398, 1217, 419, 1149, 418],
        "text": "Tagged"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1227, 398, 1239, 398, 1240, 419, 1227, 419],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1249, 398, 1262, 398, 1262, 420, 1249, 419],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1281, 398, 1376, 397, 1375, 420, 1281, 420],
        "text": "2/04/2019"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [51, 412, 214, 414, 213, 435, 50, 433],
      "text": "Tax ID Number",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [57, 414, 92, 414, 92, 434, 58, 434],
        "text": "Tax"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [103, 414, 125, 414, 125, 435, 104, 434],
        "text": "ID"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [134, 414, 205, 415, 203, 436, 134, 435],
        "text": "Number"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [282, 414, 470, 416, 469, 440, 281, 438],
      "text": ". 11110201201900",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [295, 417, 307, 416, 306, 436, 293, 436],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [315, 416, 470, 417, 468, 440, 314, 436],
        "text": "11110201201900"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [546, 417, 719, 420, 718, 441, 545, 438],
      "text": "Present Address",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [548, 417, 628, 420, 627, 440, 547, 438],
        "text": "Present"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [636, 420, 718, 421, 718, 440, 635, 440],
        "text": "Address"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1022, 420, 1493, 425, 1492, 451, 1021, 446],
      "text": "Permanent Bus. Addr (Same as Present Y Y/N)",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1025, 424, 1127, 424, 1126, 444, 1024, 443],
        "text": "Permanent"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1136, 424, 1185, 424, 1184, 444, 1135, 444],
        "text": "Bus."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1192, 424, 1236, 425, 1235, 445, 1190, 444],
        "text": "Addr"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1240, 425, 1294, 425, 1292, 446, 1239, 445],
        "text": "(Same"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1303, 425, 1328, 425, 1327, 447, 1302, 446],
        "text": "as"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1337, 425, 1417, 425, 1415, 449, 1335, 447],
        "text": "Present"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1426, 425, 1439, 425, 1437, 450, 1425, 449],
        "text": "Y"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1448, 425, 1492, 425, 1490, 451, 1446, 450],
        "text": "Y/N)"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [52, 440, 232, 442, 231, 464, 51, 461],
      "text": "SSS/GSIS Number.",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [58, 441, 150, 442, 149, 462, 58, 462],
        "text": "SSS/GSIS"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [157, 442, 232, 444, 230, 464, 156, 462],
        "text": "Number."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [299, 442, 437, 443, 436, 465, 298, 464],
      "text": "44402012019",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [316, 445, 436, 444, 434, 466, 314, 462],
        "text": "44402012019"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [545, 444, 712, 446, 711, 468, 545, 466],
      "text": "UNI1206 2ND FLR",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [547, 445, 629, 446, 629, 467, 547, 466],
        "text": "UNI1206"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [637, 446, 673, 447, 673, 468, 637, 467],
        "text": "2ND"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [681, 447, 712, 448, 712, 469, 681, 468],
        "text": "FLR"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1022, 448, 1191, 449, 1190, 472, 1021, 472],
      "text": "UNI1206 2ND FLR",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1025, 450, 1107, 449, 1107, 471, 1025, 473],
        "text": "UNI1206",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1114, 449, 1151, 450, 1152, 471, 1115, 471],
        "text": "2ND"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1158, 450, 1190, 451, 1191, 472, 1159, 471],
        "text": "FLR"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [55, 466, 200, 468, 199, 488, 54, 487],
      "text": "Branch Number",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [56, 467, 125, 468, 125, 489, 57, 487],
        "text": "Branch"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [135, 468, 201, 468, 200, 488, 135, 489],
        "text": "Number"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [332, 472, 365, 471, 364, 490, 332, 491],
      "text": "12",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [337, 471, 360, 471, 361, 490, 338, 490],
        "text": "12",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [551, 471, 914, 475, 913, 499, 550, 495],
      "text": "(Unit/House No. , Street , Subd/Bgy . )",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [552, 472, 674, 476, 672, 496, 551, 495],
        "text": "(Unit/House"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [680, 476, 713, 476, 711, 496, 678, 496],
        "text": "No."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [717, 476, 722, 476, 720, 496, 716, 496],
        "text": ","
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [726, 476, 791, 477, 789, 497, 725, 496],
        "text": "Street"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [795, 477, 800, 477, 798, 497, 793, 497],
        "text": ","
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [804, 476, 891, 475, 889, 499, 802, 497],
        "text": "Subd/Bgy"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [896, 475, 900, 475, 898, 499, 893, 499],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [905, 475, 914, 475, 911, 500, 902, 500],
        "text": ")"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1030, 477, 1388, 481, 1387, 505, 1029, 500],
      "text": "(Unit/House No. , Street, Subd/Bgy. )",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1030, 477, 1152, 479, 1152, 502, 1030, 500],
        "text": "(Unit/House"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1157, 479, 1189, 480, 1188, 503, 1156, 502],
        "text": "No."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1193, 480, 1198, 480, 1198, 503, 1193, 503],
        "text": ","
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1202, 480, 1276, 481, 1275, 504, 1202, 503],
        "text": "Street,"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1280, 481, 1376, 483, 1376, 505, 1280, 504],
        "text": "Subd/Bgy."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1381, 483, 1387, 483, 1387, 505, 1381, 505],
        "text": ")"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [62, 495, 197, 497, 196, 519, 61, 516],
      "text": "SAMSON ROAD",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [68, 498, 135, 497, 134, 517, 68, 516],
        "text": "SAMSON"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [147, 497, 192, 498, 191, 519, 146, 518],
        "text": "ROAD"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [545, 501, 862, 503, 861, 525, 544, 523],
      "text": "SHOPPESVILLE PLUS GREENHILLS",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [548, 502, 684, 503, 684, 524, 548, 523],
        "text": "SHOPPESVILLE"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [693, 503, 739, 503, 739, 524, 692, 524],
        "text": "PLUS"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [748, 503, 862, 504, 861, 525, 747, 524],
        "text": "GREENHILLS"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1030, 506, 1344, 509, 1343, 531, 1029, 528],
      "text": "SHOPPESVILLE PLUS GREENHILLS",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1030, 506, 1162, 509, 1162, 530, 1030, 528],
        "text": "SHOPPESVILLE",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1170, 509, 1218, 510, 1218, 530, 1170, 530],
        "text": "PLUS"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1224, 510, 1340, 511, 1341, 529, 1224, 530],
        "text": "GREENHILLS"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [54, 524, 233, 525, 232, 547, 53, 546],
      "text": "Primary Officer",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [58, 526, 137, 525, 137, 548, 57, 547],
        "text": "Primary"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [147, 525, 227, 526, 227, 548, 146, 548],
        "text": "Officer"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [279, 527, 347, 528, 346, 549, 279, 549],
      "text": ". 126",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [295, 530, 306, 528, 304, 544, 293, 546],
        "text": "."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [314, 529, 347, 533, 346, 549, 313, 544],
        "text": "126"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [552, 527, 702, 532, 701, 552, 551, 548],
      "text": "(District, Town",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [552, 528, 655, 531, 655, 551, 552, 549],
        "text": "(District,",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [659, 531, 702, 532, 701, 552, 659, 551],
        "text": "Town"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1026, 532, 1185, 537, 1184, 560, 1025, 554],
      "text": "(District, Town)",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1028, 533, 1132, 537, 1133, 558, 1028, 555],
        "text": "(District,"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1137, 537, 1183, 539, 1184, 558, 1138, 558],
        "text": "Town)"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [52, 551, 188, 555, 188, 577, 51, 573],
      "text": "Access Code",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [57, 553, 127, 554, 127, 575, 56, 573],
        "text": "Access"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [135, 554, 182, 555, 182, 577, 135, 575],
        "text": "Code"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [312, 553, 368, 557, 366, 573, 310, 568],
      "text": "126",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [337, 557, 367, 558, 366, 573, 336, 570],
        "text": "126"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [548, 554, 702, 556, 701, 578, 547, 576],
      "text": "SAN JUAN CITY",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [548, 555, 582, 555, 583, 577, 549, 577],
        "text": "SAN"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [592, 555, 638, 556, 639, 577, 593, 577],
        "text": "JUAN"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [647, 556, 696, 557, 696, 578, 648, 577],
        "text": "CITY"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1027, 562, 1171, 565, 1170, 586, 1026, 582],
      "text": "SAN JUAN CITY",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1027, 562, 1058, 563, 1059, 583, 1027, 582],
        "text": "SAN"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1070, 564, 1115, 565, 1115, 584, 1071, 583],
        "text": "JUAN"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1125, 565, 1170, 567, 1171, 585, 1126, 584],
        "text": "CITY"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [56, 581, 184, 585, 183, 605, 56, 602],
      "text": "Citizenship",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [59, 583, 181, 587, 181, 605, 57, 602],
        "text": "Citizenship"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [547, 581, 617, 584, 616, 607, 546, 604],
      "text": "(city)",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [549, 583, 617, 585, 616, 607, 550, 604],
        "text": "(city)",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1026, 588, 1093, 591, 1092, 614, 1025, 611],
      "text": "(city)",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1027, 590, 1090, 591, 1092, 611, 1029, 611],
        "text": "(city)"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [51, 606, 233, 609, 232, 631, 50, 628],
      "text": "Customer Class .",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [56, 608, 149, 609, 149, 629, 57, 629],
        "text": "Customer"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [157, 609, 217, 611, 216, 631, 157, 629],
        "text": "Class"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [228, 611, 232, 611, 231, 631, 227, 631],
        "text": "."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [549, 611, 674, 612, 673, 635, 548, 634],
      "text": "PHILIPPINES",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [549, 611, 674, 613, 675, 635, 549, 633],
        "text": "PHILIPPINES"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1023, 616, 1154, 618, 1153, 640, 1022, 637],
      "text": "PHILIPPINES",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1024, 616, 1151, 619, 1152, 639, 1024, 638],
        "text": "PHILIPPINES"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [56, 635, 234, 639, 233, 661, 55, 656],
      "text": "Market Segment .",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [56, 639, 125, 637, 124, 656, 56, 657],
        "text": "Market"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [135, 637, 214, 642, 212, 660, 134, 656],
        "text": "Segment"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [227, 643, 234, 644, 232, 661, 225, 661],
        "text": "."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [547, 639, 745, 644, 744, 666, 546, 661],
      "text": "(Province , Country)",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [549, 640, 645, 643, 646, 664, 550, 661],
        "text": "(Province"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [649, 643, 655, 643, 655, 664, 650, 664],
        "text": ","
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [659, 643, 745, 644, 746, 666, 659, 664],
        "text": "Country)"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1028, 643, 1227, 646, 1226, 669, 1027, 665],
      "text": "(Province, Country)",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1028, 644, 1130, 646, 1131, 667, 1029, 667],
        "text": "(Province,"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1135, 646, 1226, 647, 1227, 669, 1135, 667],
        "text": "Country)"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [49, 662, 266, 668, 265, 690, 49, 684],
      "text": "Solicitable Code .",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [56, 665, 182, 667, 181, 686, 56, 684],
        "text": "Solicitable"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [191, 667, 238, 670, 236, 688, 190, 686],
        "text": "Code"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [249, 671, 262, 673, 260, 690, 248, 689],
        "text": "."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [548, 668, 726, 671, 725, 692, 547, 689],
      "text": "Zip Code 1900 -",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [548, 670, 579, 672, 579, 689, 548, 687],
        "text": "Zip"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [591, 672, 635, 673, 636, 691, 591, 689],
        "text": "Code"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [658, 673, 702, 672, 703, 692, 658, 691],
        "text": "1900"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [714, 672, 725, 671, 726, 692, 714, 692],
        "text": "-"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1020, 672, 1199, 674, 1198, 696, 1019, 694],
      "text": "Zip Code 1900 -",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1024, 673, 1058, 674, 1059, 695, 1025, 694],
        "text": "Zip"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1068, 674, 1115, 675, 1116, 696, 1068, 695],
        "text": "Code"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1136, 675, 1183, 675, 1183, 696, 1136, 696],
        "text": "1900"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1193, 675, 1198, 675, 1198, 696, 1193, 696],
        "text": "-"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [46, 720, 320, 725, 319, 747, 45, 742],
      "text": "F2=View Last Maintenance",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [46, 721, 124, 723, 123, 744, 46, 740],
        "text": "F2=View"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [134, 723, 180, 724, 180, 745, 134, 744],
        "text": "Last"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [189, 724, 314, 726, 313, 745, 188, 745],
        "text": "Maintenance"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [354, 722, 492, 725, 491, 746, 353, 743],
      "text": "F8=Loan Data",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [357, 724, 435, 725, 435, 745, 357, 743],
        "text": "F8=Loan"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [445, 725, 492, 726, 491, 746, 445, 745],
        "text": "Data"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [699, 726, 976, 729, 975, 751, 698, 747],
      "text": "F10=Owners/Beneficiaries",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [702, 728, 971, 731, 970, 751, 702, 747],
        "text": "F10=Owners/Beneficiaries"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1033, 729, 1145, 731, 1145, 752, 1032, 750],
      "text": "F12=Cancel",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1035, 731, 1145, 732, 1145, 753, 1035, 750],
        "text": "F12=Cancel"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [44, 750, 294, 749, 294, 771, 45, 772],
      "text": "F7=User Defined Fields",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [46, 750, 124, 752, 124, 772, 45, 769],
        "text": "F7=User"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [133, 752, 214, 752, 214, 772, 133, 772],
        "text": "Defined"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [223, 752, 293, 750, 293, 769, 224, 771],
        "text": "Fields"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [355, 749, 661, 754, 660, 775, 354, 771],
      "text": "F9=FATCA/Substantial Owners",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [357, 750, 584, 754, 584, 774, 357, 771],
        "text": "F9=FATCA/Substantial"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [590, 754, 661, 754, 661, 776, 591, 774],
        "text": "Owners"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [695, 752, 994, 757, 993, 780, 694, 775],
      "text": "F11=Alternate Address Data",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [701, 754, 849, 756, 848, 778, 700, 776],
        "text": "F11=Alternate",
        "confidence": "Low"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [856, 756, 939, 758, 938, 779, 855, 778],
        "text": "Address"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [945, 758, 993, 760, 993, 779, 944, 779],
        "text": "Data"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [1035, 756, 1238, 759, 1237, 781, 1034, 777],
      "text": "F16=High Risk Type",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [1035, 759, 1124, 758, 1124, 779, 1035, 779],
        "text": "F16=High"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1134, 759, 1181, 760, 1181, 780, 1134, 779],
        "text": "Risk"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1191, 760, 1238, 762, 1237, 781, 1191, 780],
        "text": "Type"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

I wanted to get the value of property text (`Zip Code 1900 -`) however there is another property with same same name.
E.g., I want to extract like below:

```
Display Record
Customer Number . . 0012343345
Short Name . . . . . . SHOES AND THINGS
```

Below is my code:

```
Dim ocrProperties As azureOcrJsonProperty = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of azureOcrJsonProperty)(JsonReponse)
For Each item As PropertyInfo In ocrProperties.GetType.GetProperties()
    If item.PropertyType.IsNested Then

        Dim TypeHolder as Type = item.GetValue(ocrProperties)
        For Each subitem As PropertyInfo In TypeHolder.GetType.GetProperties()
            Formatted_JSon = subitem.Name & ": " & subitem.GetValue(TypeHolder).ToString 
        Next
    Else
        Formatted_JSon = item.Name & ": " & item.GetValue(ocrProperties).ToString
    End If
Next

Public Class azureOcrJsonProperty
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property recognitionResults As recognitionResults
End Class

Public Class recognitionResults
    Public Property page As Integer
    Public Property clockwiseOrientation As decimal
    Public Property width As Integer
    Public Property height As Integer
    Public Property unit As String
    Public Property lines As lines
End Class

Public Class lines
    Public Property boundingBox As String()
    Public Property text As decimal
    Public Property words As words
End Class

Public Class words
    Public Property boundingBox As String()
    Public Property text As decimal
End Class
```

I am getting below error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'Get_Customer_Info+recognitionResults' because the type requires a
> JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix
> this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
> type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
> like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by *the value of key text ("Zip Code 1900 -")*?  `"Zip Code 1900 -"` is the value of the property `"text"` so it's not quite clear what you want to extract.  Your desired output value (either text value or JSON value as appropriate) would be ideal.

Comment: Hi dbc, I have updated my comment. I wanted to get the value of the property as text

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the first `text` property, something like: `dim firstTextValue = JObject.Parse(yourJson)("text").ToString()`?. If not, follow the same pattern to get other properties' values (e.g., `JObject.Parse(yourJson)("words")(0)("boundingBox").ToArray()`) or deserialize the JSON to a class model.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. The given above JSON response is repeated multiple times in the response. So Do i need to run it in loop to read each text property ? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: That's an array of objects (if you enclose it in `[` + `]`). So, a `JArray`: `dim result = JArray.Parse(yourJson)(1)("text").ToString()`. Or deserialize to a List of class objects.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. I was trying to arrive the code however i am unable to.. Do you have any code reference so that I can use it to complete?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here. I can help you to parse this JSON. You need to post the whole JSON though. What you posted is an partial fragment, which should be contained in an array. BTW, remember to prefix a nickname with `@`. I wasn't notified of your comment, I came here by chance.

Comment: @Jimi - Thanks for the response. I have modified my question with full JSON and some additional information which I believe will help you to understand about my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON structure itself is quite simple, see the resulting class model at the bottom of this page.
The main Class (**`OcrResults`**) exposes the **`Serialize()`** and **`Deserialize(json As String)`** public methods that perform the standard operations.

To deserialize the JSON, call the `Deserialize()` method as:

```
Dim ocrResults = New OcrResults()
Dim ocrObjects = ocrResults.Deserialize(json)
```

or

```
 Dim ocrObjects = New OcrResults(json).Deserialize()
```

The resulting class object can be modified and serialized back (if required) to the original JSON structure, calling the `Serialize()` method:

```
Dim ocrResults = New OcrResults()
Dim ocrObjects = ocrResults.Deserialize(json)
'(...)

Dim newJson As String = ocrResults.Serialize(ocrObjects)
```

Since this JSON contains the result of an OCR procedure - where the bounding polygons of the recognized text are referenced as an array on integers - I've added a (slightly *verbose*) `JsonConverter`, (**`BoundingBoxConverter`**), to convert the arrays on integers to arrays of `Point` structures (and back to arrays of integers when the class model is serialized).

This eliminates one step if/when the polygons are drawn around the recognized Text parts (usually, the drawing classes, as the `GraphicsPath` class, accept an array of `Point`/`PointF` as argument).

---

The deserialized object's **`Lines`** property is a `List(Of Line)` classes.
Each `Line().Text` property contains a full sequence of recognized text, while the `Line().Words()` Lists contain the single parts of the same sequence.

The full line can be extracted using LINQ queries in different ways.
For example, as described in the question, the lines:

```
Display Record Customer Number . . 0012343345 Short Name . . . . . . SHOES AND THINGS
```

Can be extracted as:

```
Dim ocrObjects = New OcrResults(json).Deserialize()

Dim searchResult = ocrObjects.RecognitionResults.
    SelectMany(Function(r) r.Lines.
    SkipWhile(Function(ln) Not ln.Text.Contains("Display Record")).
    TakeWhile(Function(ln) Not ln.Text.StartsWith("Name"))).ToList()
```

The **`searchResult`** list contains all the `Line` objects in sequence, starting from `"Display Record"` to `"Short Name . . . . . . SHOES AND THINGS"`.

To print the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", searchResult.Select(Function(ln) ln.Text)))
```

equivalent to:

```
For Each line As OcrResults.Line In searchResult
    Console.Write(line.Text)
Next
```

Extract the first **`Line`** object where the Text property contains `"Zip Code 1900"`:

```
Dim zipCode = ocrObjects.RecognitionResults.
    SelectMany(Function(r) r.Lines).
    First(Function(ln) ln.Text.Contains("Zip Code 1900"))

Dim zipCodeText = zipCode.Text
Dim zipPoints = zipCode.BoundingBox
```

or, assign the first recognized *Page* to a new object, so you can use its **`Lines`** objects directly:

```
Dim ocrFirstPage = ocrObjects.RecognitionResults(0)

Dim zipCode = ocrFirstPage.Lines.
    First(Function(ln) ln.Text.Contains("Zip Code 1900"))

Dim zipCodeText = zipCode.Text
Dim zipPoints = zipCode.BoundingBox
```

---

**Drawing the Text sections:**

Each line of recognized Text specifies the polygon that contains the string.
To draw the Polygons corresponding to the **`boundingBox`** array of Point structures of each Line of text, one of the

Each `OcrObjects.RecognitionResults` class has a **`ClockwiseOrientation`** property that defines the rotation angle of the Text as identified by the OCR.
This angle can be used to rotate the Graphics (or to strighten the Polygon, eventually).

For example, using a Windows Forms `PictureBox` control as canvas and a GraphicsPath as the container of the Polygons:

```
Dim ocrObjects As OcrResults.Results = Nothing

' (...)
' Somewhere... 
 ocrObjects = New OcrResults(json).Deserialize()
 PictureBox1.Invalidate()
 ' (...)

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If ocrObjects Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim ocr = ocrObjects.RecognitionResults(0)
    'Dim angle As Single = Convert.ToSingle(ocr.ClockwiseOrientation)
    Using path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4
            path.AddPolygon(ocr.Lines(i).BoundingBox)
        Next
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        'e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-angle)
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path)
    End Using
End Sub
```

This will draw the first 5 polygons, giving this result:

[image: Json OCR Results]

---

**`OcrResults` class model**:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class OcrResults
    Private jSettings As JsonSerializerSettings
    Private jsonInput As String = String.Empty
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(json As String)
        jsonInput = json
        jSettings = New JsonSerializerSettings() With {
            .Converters = New JsonConverter() {New BoundingBoxConverter()}
        }
    End Sub

    Public Class Results
        Public Property Status As String
        Public Property RecognitionResults As List(Of RecognitionResult)
    End Class

    Public Class RecognitionResult
        Public Property Page As Long
        Public Property ClockwiseOrientation As Double
        Public Property Width As Long
        Public Property Height As Long
        Public Property Unit As String
        Public Property Lines As List(Of Line)
    End Class

    Public Class Line
        Public Property BoundingBox As Point()
        Public Property Text As String
        Public Property Words As List(Of Word)
    End Class
    Public Class Word
        Public Property BoundingBox As Point()
        Public Property Text As String

        <JsonProperty(NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
        Public Property Confidence As String
    End Class


    Public Function Serialize(model As Results) As String
        Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, jSettings)
    End Function

    Public Function Deserialize() As Results
        Return Deserialize(jsonInput)
    End Function

    Public Function Deserialize(json As String) As Results
        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Results)(json, jSettings)
    End Function

    Public Class BoundingBoxConverter
        Inherits JsonConverter

        Public Overrides Function CanConvert(t As Type) As Boolean
            Return t = GetType(Point())
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, t As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
            If reader.TokenType = JsonToken.Null Then Return Nothing
            If reader.TokenType <> JsonToken.StartArray Then Return existingValue

            Dim values As New List(Of Integer)()
            While reader.TokenType <> JsonToken.EndArray
                Dim pointPart = reader.ReadAsInt32()
                If pointPart IsNot Nothing Then values.Add(pointPart.Value)
            End While
            Return New Point() {
                New Point(values(0), values(1)),
                New Point(values(2), values(3)),
                New Point(values(4), values(5)),
                New Point(values(6), values(7))
            }
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, untypedValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
            If untypedValue Is Nothing Then
                serializer.Serialize(writer, Nothing)
                Return
            End If

            If TypeOf untypedValue Is Point() Then
                Dim points = DirectCast(untypedValue, Point())
                If points.Length = 4 Then
                    Dim values() = points.SelectMany(Function(p) New Integer() {p.X, p.Y}).ToArray()
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, values)
                    Return
                End If
                Throw New Exception("Invalid array of [Point]")
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```