# Get all values from property with LINQ from JSON?

Tags: vb.net, linq, json.net

I'm having trouble sorting out the exact syntax to properly query my JSON response.

My API endpoint returns some JSON as follows:

```
 {
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResults": [
    {
      "page": 1,
      "clockwiseOrientation": 0.14,
      "width": 2835,
      "height": 2241,
      "unit": "pixel",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": [
            25,
            11,
            324,
            15,
            323,
            51,
            24,
            46
          ],
          "text": "Custom Report",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                37,
                11,
                171,
                14,
                172,
                49,
                38,
                48
              ],
              "text": "Custom"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                193,
                15,
                322,
                17,
                323,
                49,
                194,
                49
              ],
              "text": "Report"
            }
          ]
        }...
```

What is important to note is that is that the root element will only contain 1 `recognitionResults` array. Inside this array it will contain many arrays of `lines`. Inside each line I have a property of `text`, I'll also have a property of `words` that also contains a property of `text`. I'm only concerned with the property `text` that is the direct child of `lines`.

I'm attempting to select all of the `text` properties into a list of strings.

vb.net code:

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.GetFileName(strFilePath) & ".json", JToken.Parse(strResult).ToString())
Dim c1 As JArray = CType(tmpObj("recognitionResults"), JArray)
Dim c2 = (From s In c1.Children() Select s("text")).ToList()
```

This throws an exception that the `JArray` has an invalid key; an int is expected.

I also thought I could just query it with LINQ directly:

```
Dim c3 = (From s In tmpObj Select s("text")).ToList()
```

This throws an exception that it cannot access a child value on `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jproperty`

Lastly, I've also tried this:

```
 Dim c2 = (From p In tmpObj("recognitionResults")("lines").Children() Select p("text"))
```

I'm really stuck at this point.  I think I just have a syntax problem in how I am trying to select.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See the `OcrResults` class object and its usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59433740/7444103). It includes the rendering of the polygons represented in the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) with a wildcard to get the information you want from the JSON more easily:

```
Dim token As JToken = JToken.Parse(json)
Dim lines As List(Of String) = _
    (From t In token.SelectTokens("..lines[*].text") Select CStr(t)).ToList()
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zlenga